# Check whether Conditional Formatting is applied or not

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Using Excel VBA code, is there any way by which I can check whether a
particular cell has satisfied Conditional Formatting or not?

I have data in a single column with than 80000 cells.

I used the following code but it gives same value for Interior.ColorIndex or Interior.PatternIndex or Font.Bold irrespective of whether the Conditional Formatting is applied or not

```
Sub Check_CF()
    MsgBox Range("B4").Interior.PatternColorIndex
End Sub
```

My conditional formatting rule is not important. I can change the rule if I am able to check whether it is applied or not.

Answer (score 3):

Found this rather long article with example functions on the subject that might be of help to you:
http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html

Comment: In order to successfully use the routines provided by xldynamic, I had to make a small modification so that the behaviour becomes independent of what the currently selected cell is.
Changed 
`sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlA1, xlR1C1)`
to
`sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlA1, xlR1C1, , oFC.AppliesTo)`